# Echoing LEFT() query

Tags: php, html, mysql, sqlsrv

I have this SQL query that works perfectly as it is, my problem now is that I cannot `echo` it because its being used in `LEFT()`

This is the entire code.

```
$empid='D001'
$sql = "Select 
           DISTINCT TOP 1 
        LEFT (employeeidno, 4) as deptcode,
        RIGHT(employeeidno, 7) as empno
        FROM employeemasterfile 
        WHERE 
           LEFT (employeeidno, 4)='D001' 
        ORDER BY 
           RIGHT(employeeidno, 7) DESC";

include 'query/sqlsrv_query-global.php';

if(sqlsrv_num_rows($query) > 0) {
  while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     $accountcode=$row['deptcode'] + 1;
     echo "<option value='".$row['deptcode'].":".$accountcode."'>".$row['deptcode']."</option>";
  }
}
```

Is there a way to fix this? I tried to use `AS`, unfortunately no luck.

Comment: You are selecting records where `LEFT (employeeidno, 4)='D001'` - so the `deptcode` = `D001` and the you are doing `$accountcode=$row['deptcode'] + 1;` which is trying to add 1 to it.

Comment: Oh I see, that's why, I need to separate the character and the integer first. I forgot. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to generate the next employee's id, probably `$accountcode=$row['empno'] + 1` is more appropriate here.

Comment: @Zhorov, yeah, I didn't notice. Honest mistake on my end. :)

Comment: @pjustindaryll And probably `$empid` should be a parameter in your SQL statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get the next employee number then

```
$accountcode=$row['deptcode'] + 1;
```

as `$row['deptcode']` is `D001` will produce a warning

> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in ...

and the result will be `1`.

If instead you do

```
$row['deptcode']++;
```

this will adjust it correctly and you will get `D002`

Comment: ````$row['deptcode']++;```` is much cleaner than ````$row['deptcode']+1;````. Thanks for this.